# Backing up data of protected apps

Tags: backup, protected-apps

I am using adb to backup some applications' data from my old phone to my new one. It worked fine for all apps except the one I purchased, it took me a while to figure that out since Android and its log were not showing any errors, instead it was telling me that the backup is complete and the log says:

```
D/BackupManagerService( 2121): Full backup processing complete.
D/BackupManagerService( 2121): Full backup pass complete.
```

and the generated backup file has a size of 549B (bytes)

Note: it says "Full" but it actually for a single package.

After searching I now know that Google added some kind of protection in Android 4.1+ to prevent people from coping protected applications between phones. However, I am not interested in backing up the apk itself as I can download the app from Google Play Store, instead I want to backup the data so I can restore it in my new phone and not have to deal with setting the application again.

Is there a way to do that without needing root access to the device?

Note: the old device is Nexus 4 (5.1.1 Cyanogen + root), while the new one is Nexus 6P (6.0 stock, no root).

Comment: Why don't you use Google Sync to back up application data?

Comment: @SarpSTA: Google Sync works only for google apps. Google apps are already synced between Android phones if you use the same gmail account so I don't need to back them up. I want to backup third party applications that have no cloud sync abilities.

Comment: Developer can also prevent backup for their apps (e.g. WhatsApp returning empty data). If you're rooted, perhaps you can use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), but I'm not sure if there's other way for non-rooted device.

Comment: Give us the link for the app whose data wasn't backed up by ADB. I suspect the flag [`android:allowbackup="false"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#allowbackup) and if that's the case then forget backing up the app's data without root.

Comment: @AndrewT. I use TitaniumBackup with all my previous phones, but I am trying to see if I can live with a non-rooted phone since google added the new permission control in Android 6. Not being able to backup your own data is nonsense and Google should provide a way to solve it.

Comment: @Firelord the app I need to backup is "JuiceSSH" I also tested with "swype" (but I don't care about backing it up) and it also didn't backup. I think you are right about the flag.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the title from saying "purchased apps" to "protected apps" since I found, thanks to @[Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord), the problem that prevents me from doing the backup. These apps have the flag `android:allowbackup` set to `false` and that will not only prevent backing up the application apk, but also its data and setting and will prevent you from restoring a backup if you managed to have one.
I tried doing a backup from my rooted phone using "Titanium backup", unpacked the apk using "apktool" changed the flag to `true`, singed the apk with my keys and restored the modified TitaniumBackup into the rooted phone, that allowed me to do the `adb backup` of the data. However, restoring the data to the original app on the new phone didn't work.

So the only solutions I know of are these two:

- Use my modified and signed apk instead of the play store version, but that means I have to do the modification and signing whenever there is a new update of the application.
- Or, root the new phone and use TitanimuBackup to restore settings.

and unfortunately it seems impossible to do it otherwise, not very convenient.